# Twilio send client in queue call all agents, tell them the callers name and connect first one with client

Tags: twilio

I am trying to solve this problem for hours now. I would like to implement this scenario:

- Client calls and Twilio puts him to a queue
- Client should listen to holding music
- My REST-API get called with the callers number and returns the callers name
- All agents are getting called now.
- If a agent picks up Twilio tells him the callers name and connects the agent and the client.

Is this even possible with Twilio ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely possible. How far did you get? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: So I tried to send the client to a queue, which works with TwiML Bins. He hears the hold music, which is fine. I don't know how to call the client simultaneously now.

I tried to accomplish this with Twilio Studios and TwilBins as well but as the are synchronous I don't know how to do two things at the same time.